# How can I add many UserControls to StackPanel without freeze?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-controls, async-await, uwp

i try to develop a equivalent to a android app (just for fun / 2 learn) and i try to add round about 3500 UserControls to my GUI in a StackPanel.

One UserControl contain 2 textblocks (titel and subtitle), two buttons and one image.

If i add the controls in the UI thread the thread will be blocked for round about 6 sec. But an asynchronous thread will throw an exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

```
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            MyUserControl1 News = new MyUserControl1();

            // EXAMPLE
            for (int i = 0; i < 3500; i++)
            {
                News= new MyUserControl1();

                News.Titel = i + " Titel";
                News.Untertitel = i + " Untertitel";

                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    UserControlCollection.Children.Add(News);
                });
            }

        });
```

What can I do to resolve this fault? thx for your help

Comment: Don't add 3500 controls in the first place.  Something's wrong with your UI if you need that.  You need to redesign it so that there isn't as many rendered controls at any given point in time.

Comment: use MVVM and bind children to ObservableCollection

Comment: The answer from @RTDev is right, make sure to enable UI virtualization. If your data set can be loaded asynchronously, you should consider implementing some kind of data virtualization as well

Comment: you may subscribe to each News Loaded event and create next News after it. This should keep your UI thread responsive.

Comment: thx guys :) I virtualization the ui and use MVVM and the performance is incredibly high! No freez :)